# change text of rows in type matrix surveyjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, surveyjs

I am building best employee survey project using [surveyjs](https://surveyjs.io/Overview/Library/). When working in matrix type, I get trouble how to change text "employee1,employee2,employee3" with real name employee
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT7PQ.jpg).
so far here is my code:

```js
var json = {
    title: "Software developer survey.",
    pages: [
   {
       title: "Part 1",

       questions: [
           {
               type: "matrix",
               name: "Question1",
               //isAllRowRequired: true,
               title: "Please indicate if you agree or disagree with the following statements",
               columns: [
                   {
                       value: 1,
                       text: "Strongly Disagree"
                   }, {
                       value: 2,
                       text: "Disagree"
                   }, {
                       value: 3,
                       text: "Neutral"
                   }, {
                       value: 4,
                       text: "Agree"
                   }, {
                       value: 5,
                       text: "Strongly Agree"
                   }
               ],
               rows: [
                   {
                       value: "valueEmployee1",
                       text: "Employee1 ![Employee1](https://bezone.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/soeharto.jpg =50x50)"
                   }, {
                       value: "valueEmployee2",
                       text: "Employee2"
                   }, {
                       value: "valueEmployee3",
                       text: "Employee3"
                   }
               ]
           },
           //
       ]
   },
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can add matrix rows dynamically:

```
var json = {
    questions: [
        {
            type: "matrix",
            name: "score",
            title: "Please score the employees in the list",
            columns: [
                {
                    value: 1,
                    text: "Bad"
                }, {
                    value: 2,
                    text: "So-so"
                }, {
                    value: 3,
                    text: "Good enough"
                }, {
                    value: 4,
                    text: "Good"
                }, {
                    value: 5,
                    text: "Excellent"
                }
            ],
            rows: [
            ]
        }
    ]
};

window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);

var q = survey.getQuestionByName("score");

var employees = [{ id: "id1", name: "John"}, { id: "id2", name: "Ben"}, { id: "id3", name: "Chack"}]

employees.forEach(function(employee) {
  q.rows.push(new Survey.ItemValue(employee.id, employee.name));
});
```

Here is the working sample - https://plnkr.co/edit/OMBt1n02Qc8f5znUmOHE?p=preview

Comment: ok, the script can display names and the survey produce ids with its score. but, then, how i can iterate the result.data so i could sent id and scores to database?is there any example to do that.thanks

Comment: You can check this thread https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs/issues/1604